# Is this group given presentation isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and why?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

We have the group $G = \langle a, \,b \; | \; a^2b^2ab^{-1}, \, a^3b^4a^{-2}b^{-3}\rangle$.

Obviously $G/G' = \mathbb{Z}_2$. Is it true that $G = \mathbb{Z}_2$ or equivalently that $G'=1$? It is possible to write down the presentation of $G'$, it has two generators and three relations, however it is not clear from that presentation that $G'=1$. Probably $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$, because there are some coset enumerative algoritms which show that $a$ generates $G$. If this is the case, can we show this by hand?

Another question which immediately comes to mind is the following. What is a probability that randomly chosen group $\langle a, \,b \;| \; r(a,b), \, s(a,b) \rangle$ is finite? Of course this question can be generalized to balanced presentations with any finite number of generators.

**Edit:** The answer to the original question is yes ($G\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2$), as indicated by Francesco Polizzi, using a computer verification. I would also be interested by a more "explicit" proof, which could be a conceptual argument, or an explicit way of writing, say, $ab$ as a product of conjugates of relators (from which such a writing of $a^2$ and $b^2$ would quickly follow).

Comment: I guess you already checked that the abelianization of $G'$ is trivial? For the "random" question, there are many non-equivalent definition of what a "random" presentation should be.

Comment: Yes, of course it's easy to show that $G' = G''$. I am not a specialist in probability theory. But intuitively we all understand what "randomly chosen" means. For example, what if I write down 10000 presentations without any particular preference? Which part of these 10000 would define finite groups? Does the answer depend on our particular definition of "randomly chosen"? Of course, any references are welcome.

Comment: I don't believe that we intuitively understand what a randomly chosen presentation is. How are you going to decide how long $r$ and $s$ should be?

Comment: Yes that's one model (fixed number of relator, uniform distribution over the $k$-ball). Gromov defined another, more interesting model, with a density parameter (with a growing number of relators as the ball becomes larger).

Comment: "with bare hands, using only pen and paper" is quite self-contradictory :) also I think it does not belong on the title

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to alter the question after receiving an answer, in a way that makes the answer no longer relevant. I'm going to revert the tltle and change the body slightly so that Francesco's answer is still relevant.

Comment: I don't see the research angle of the first question (i.e. the one whether the given group $G$ is cyclic of order 2) -- firstly it can be solved by standard methods within milliseconds and secondly there are thousands of similar groups about which one could ask the same question. The second general question is unclear since no choice of probability space is made in the question. For these reasons I have voted to migrate this question to math.SE. -- There it could also be explained in detail that it is not clear what is meant by a "randomly chosen group" of the specified form.

Comment: I am terrified with your answers. You show the very awful aspects of "scientific society". Who are you to judge this poor question? "I don't see the research angle of the first question", why do you care about it at all? Can you explain, please? If you don't like this question, just go on, why do you care about it? This question is a yell of helplessness of us, people. It turns out that without computer we are unable to answer very easy questions. This was a great insight for me, that $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$. Who are you to judge this insight?

Comment: All of you point me out that "second general question is unclear since no choice of probability space is made in the question". Ok, make any choice of this space of probabilities and answer the question with this choice, why not? But instead of this you vote for something. Are you kidding me? Everyone feels obliged to come here and point me out that  "question is unclear since no choice of probability space is made". A-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a.

Comment: I think that it is reasonable to ask about a proof which is not just running an algorithm (e.g., as I mentioned elsewhere, writing explicitly, say, $ab$ as a product of relators, since GAP doesn't provide this); however I agree it was awkward to just discard the answer to the original question because you didn't like it. Recall the original question was "is this group cyclic on 2 elements", and not "I know that this group has 2 elements, can you prove it?" Well, I'll edit, and hope the question will not be migrated since it's not so obvious.

Comment: By the way, this is an exercise in Magnus, Karras, Solitar Combinatorial Group Theory. They ask to prove that $G'=G''$, did they realize that $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and their question in a sense is trivial?

Comment: Possibly they didn't realize (no GAP!), but anyway this is a reasonable exercise to compute a presentation for a subgroup of index 2 (in the same fashion, proving that there infinitely many primes is trivial if one assumes the Riemann hypothesis...).

Comment: Yes, of course it is reasonable exercise.

Comment: Samarkand, I think it would be much better if you would ask the second question (about random group presentations) in a separate post, since it's an entirely different question. This would also give you an opportunity to sharpen the question: think about which probability measure would be the most meaningful to you and why, rather than leave the choice to the reader. (Just a suggestion.) I agree with YCor that the first question is substantial enough to stand on its own, and that it should not be migrated.

Comment: Given that this presentation simplifies very directly after the substitution $c=ab^-1$ and it is also amenable to computations via computer algebra systems (probably because this rewrite system is one of the first chosen by the computer), I don't see the research merit of this question. If the second question was distinct with random variables clearly defined, it would be appropriate for this site. I agree with previous statements that this question should be closed or migrated in its current form.

Answer (score 17):

This [GAP4](http://www.gap-system.org/) script checks that the group $G$ is actually isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$.

```
f:=FreeGroup("a", "b");
a:=f.1; b:=f.2;
G:=f/[a^2*b^2*a*b^(-1), a^3*b^4*a^(-2)*b^(-3)];
Order(G);
```

Comment: Well, I formulated my question incorrectly. I am not interested in the bare fact that $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$. I do not understand how to show this by hand. I amazed with the difficulty which appears when I am trying to deduce some identities. I do not see how to deduce $a^2$. Moreover, at the first look this group looks like a non-abelian one. So, It was a great surprise for me that $G$ is actually $Z_2$

Comment: In the reference page of GAP there is a list of books and papers concerning the algorithms used. 
http://www.gap-system.org/Doc/references.html#Si94
For finitely presented groups, Johnson's *Presentation of Groups* and Sims' *Computation with finitely presented groups* are especially useful. 

You can surely show that the group is $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ by hand using the algorithms explained in these books, since they are precisely  the algorithms that the software uses.  However, I do not know how complicate this can be.

Comment: I'd expect that if GAP detects that the group has order 2, it can also explicitly write $a^2$, $b^2$ and $ab$ as an explicit product of conjugates of relators?

Comment: @YCor I don't think that is totally straightforward. I believe there is an implementation of coset enumeration that can print out human readable proofs, but I don't  know whether it is generally available.